How to create a custom role with specific permissions in Airflow using AirflowSecurityManager or other?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to create custom roles with specific permissions in Apache Airflow. I have a dictionary that contains the role names and their corresponding permissions. Here is an example of the dictionary:
roles_permissions = {
    "Role1": ["can_dag_read", "can_dag_edit"],
    "Role2": ["can_dag_read"]
}

I have found that AirflowSecurityManager might be the way to go for managing roles and permissions in Airflow, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it to create these custom roles programmatically.
Could someone provide an example or guide me on how to create these custom roles with the permissions defined in the dictionary?
